# Getting CORS error when trying to play videos in YouTube

Tags: 22.04, youtube

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Whenever I try to play videos in YouTube, it just keeps loading. I am getting a CORS error too. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu, but it didn't solve anything.

[image: screenshot]